# Python generators: Errors visible only after commenting

Tags: python, error-handling, generator

I was trying following python code to simulate 'tail' command of *nix systems.

```
import sys
def tail(f):
    print 'in tail with ',f
    f.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

if(len(sys.argv) >= 2):
    print 'calling tail'
    tail(open(sys.argv[1],'r'))
else:
    print 'Give file path.\n'
```

I did an error (missed importing time module). However, what's odd is that no error was getting thrown and program was quitting silently.
Output (before commenting):

```
$ python tail.py /var/log/dmesg 
calling tail
```

However if I comment lines following the one using the time module, the error does get thrown.

```
import sys
def tail(f):
    print 'in tail with ',f
    f.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        #     continue
        # yield line

if(len(sys.argv) >= 2):
    print 'calling tail'
    tail(open(sys.argv[1],'r'))
else:
    print 'Give file path.\n'
```

Output (after commenting)

```
$ python tail.py /var/log/dmesg 
calling tail
in tail with  <open file '/var/log/dmesg', mode 'r' at 0x7fc8fcf1e5d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tail.py", line 14, in <module>
    tail(open(sys.argv[1],'r'))
  File "tail.py", line 8, in tail
    time.sleep(0.1)
NameError: global name 'time' is not defined
```

Can anyone please explain why the error was not getting thrown in case one (before commenting)? Shouldn't a error be thrown as soon as interpreter comes on that line?

Corrected program:

```
import sys
import time
def tail(f):
    print 'in tail with ',f
    f.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = f.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        yield line

if(len(sys.argv) >= 2):
    print 'calling tail'
    t = tail(open(sys.argv[1],'r'))
    for i in t:
        print i
else:
    print 'Give file path.\n'
```

Output:

```
$ python tail.py hello.txt 
calling tail
in tail with  <open file 'hello.txt', mode 'r' at 0x7fac576b95d0>
hello there 1

hello there 2

hello there 3
```

Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Doesn't the if condition get satisfied (in the second call) only if you don't yield line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**

First one is instantiating a generator (but not assigning it to a variable) and second one is a function call.

---

**Long Answer**

This is because of dynamic type checking of python, when you have the `yield` statement, your function behaves as a generator and this line -

```
tail(open(sys.argv[1],'r'))
```

means that you are **instantiating** the generator **not calling a function**. You'll get that error when you assign this instance to some variable and call the `next` method for generator which **actually** fires it up i.e. -

```
t = tail(open(sys.argv[1],'r')) # t is a generator here 
t.next()
```

The other case in which you removed the `yield` statement, it started behaving as a normal function which means  - `tail(open(sys.argv[1],'r'))` is a function call now, and hence it threw an error.

*What I meant by dynamic is python doesn't check these kind of errors until it reaches that statement, which in first case wasn't.*

Answer (score 3):

With `yield` in the function, it is a generator. Generator functions only execute their contained code when the next value is requested. Simply calling a generator function merely creates that generator object. If you do so without doing anything with that object, such as looping through it, nothing will happen.

Removing the `yield` makes the function evaluate eagerly, so its code is actually executed.

If you actually iterated over the generator, it would produce an error if/when `readline()` produced an empty line. Since such an empty line can only occur at the end of a file (what look like blank lines actually contain a single linefeed character), putting it in a loop doesn't make sense anyway. Instead of this:

```
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
        time.sleep(0.1)
        continue
    yield line
```

Use this:

```
for line in f:
    yield line
```

And instead of this:

```
if(len(sys.argv) >= 2):
    print 'calling tail'
    tail(open(sys.argv[1],'r'))
```

You should actually execute the generator's contents, with something like this:

```
if(len(sys.argv) >= 2):
    print 'calling tail'
    for line in tail(open(sys.argv[1],'r')):
        print line
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The delay and loop were there to wait for input so that it behaves similar to tail command on linux like 'tail -f hello.txt'. Please see my edits in the original post with output. I was simultaneously adding text to the file hello.txt in another terminal.